# what is the name of this wheel found in toys which rotates freely?

Tags: control-engineering

[image: wheel base]

I have tried doing search by image on few popular Internet search engines but could not get it. (sorry, it picked up lot of dust and a bit ugly to see).

I want to know the name of such wheel and where can I probably purchase it by mentioning parameters. Are there any alternate designs?

Comment: You have been given a good answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/522372/152903

Comment: Definitely yes. I wanted to delete there and post here as it is more relevant forum. Moreover I wanted to know where can I probably purchase and also names of alternate designs.

Comment: I have flagged the question there for moderation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically its called a bump wheel, these are rarely seen anymore but so far can be found on ebay and aliexpress. I'll paste a link for you.
https://www.ebay.com/itm/224088720767?hash=item342cba857f:g:KrMAAOSwfWpfBaoI&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAABABbKgMhnpIu%2Fmmi%2BDmgsxLJgY%2FLVD69CEw%2Bef6155ZvLLXw826FpEDIPLpVw5bZnCB9kE9aGjzJvgZJYv9A%2BrUFLNa2iclW3%2Ba6pjwhbbdAXiSHMllxsSZMs65dJf5FPg60Ml%2FskWeSGNKrMxbrDfqGm3H7EjNvKCr3BnK8m2%2BtuNqaQhH2f4n2I88%2Fdn7%2B6W18TEtVhbcW%2B4cC7vjN%2FApmqTkCiDLYN7JbkRLkv9VPYQxVwKq9ti%2FxaGdUgkH%2F%2B7GJeluzTCB5l8KJF%2Bz2gZdkhVhCxKZ0yM4kZWuWxc7BQKSA6FKezcRWXoosWZ%2FhwZZe3qquwdRNDw7gJofLS4ZA%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR-b74tWbYQ

Comment: Welcome to E.SE, Johnathan. The site does not allow shopping questions and so your answer is facilitating a breach of the rules. One of the reasons is that shopping questions quickly become out of date - when your link dies, for example. Instead help the OP by giving the name of the component so they can do their own search.